# Add facebook event to MacOS Catalina calendar

Tags: catalina, calendar, facebook

On older *MacOS* version I used to have a *Facebook* account so all the events I participated or was interested into appeared in the *Calendar* application.

What is the best way to achieve this now that the *Facebook* account disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

- Open Facebook.com on your Mac
- Go to Events > [Calendar](https://www.facebook.com/events/calendar/)
- On the right side, click on "Upcoming Events" :
  [image: Facebook Calendar]
- A .ics file will be downloaded, and you just need to open it in the Calendar.app